# How to list, view & open files (NOT prgrammatically) in isolated storage?

Tags: isolatedstorage

I remember there being a "Isolated Storage Browser" utility, but can no longer find it. Is there really one?

How can I list, view & open files (NOT prgrammatically) in isolated storage?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for that one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezabwsbk%28VS.80%29.aspx